# "Request = Undefined" cuando hago click en retroceder en el navegador

Tags: django, apache2, configuración, error404, safari

Tengo un problema con mi aplicación de django, cuando accedo a catalogo/dormitorios (por ejemplo) y doy para retroceder a la anterior pagina me salta "not found" y en la url aparece midominio/undefined. Pero esto solo ocurre en apple.
Cuando uso el ordenador que tiene instalado windows no me da ese error y la app funciona correctamente.

Urls.py (Project)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mueblesApp.urls')),

]
```

Urls.py (App)

```
    from django.urls import path
    from mueblesApp import views
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib import admin
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home, name="Home"),
        path('catalogo/<int:familiaId>',views.catalogo, name="Catalogo" ),
        path('productoInfo/<int:productoId>', views.productoInfo, name="ProductoInfo"),
]
```

No se a que se puede deber ese error. Lo tengo alojado en mi servidor con Apache.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RVvL.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjeHq.png

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: Puedes copiar y pegar el código en la pregunta, no como imagen.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a una versión de javascript, no se si desactualizada o que no funciona correctamente en los dispositivos Apple.
Lo he solucionado haciendo una redirección dentro del host virtual de Apache. Es un pequeño apaño pero funciona bien.